# redirecting search result, form submit

Tags: search, redirect, yii, form-submit

in my index page I have this code to call search action:

```
$this->renderPartial('search');
```

and this is the search action code:

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

            if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
                $q = $_GET['city'];
                $criteria->compare('fileName', $q, true, 'OR');
                $criteria->compare('tags', $q, true, 'OR');
                $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider("Files", array('criteria' => $criteria));
                $this->redirect('result', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
            }

            $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider("Files", array('criteria' => $criteria));
            $this->render('search');
```

and this is the search view:

```
        <form method="get">
<?php
        $url = CHtml::normalizeUrl(array("files/search"));
        $model = Files::model();
        $c = new FilesController('view');
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'id'=>'autocomplete',
            'attribute'=>$model->fileName,
            'name'=>'city',
            'source'=>$c->actionAutoComplete(),
            // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
            'options'=>array(
                'minLength'=>'1',
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'style'=>'height:20px;',
                'placeholder'=>'search',
                'value'=>'isset($_GET["city"]) ? CHtml::encode($_GET["city"]) : "" ',
                ),)); 
?>
        <input type="submit" value="search" />


         </form>
```

I want to show the search results in another view, so once clicked the search submit button I want to redirect to another view to show the results, but in this code the search result is shown in the index page.
so how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either set the url that you want your form to be send, like:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('anotherController/anotherView'),
    'method' => 'post',
));
```

or you can redirect to another page after your done in index, like:

```
$this->redirect(array('anotherController/anotherView'));
```

Comment: of course there are because you are using "<form>" tags, and I have shown you how to use yii form with bootstrap, to help you develop faster.And don't forget to use "$this->endWidget();" after your form.

Comment: firstly I used CActiveForm instead of bootstrap, then I used GET method to be suitable with my code instead of POST...thank you